# Getting coordinates of objects in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, position

So based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9027249/confused-by-document-dimensions-in-javascript/9027284#9027284) I asked, what's the most reliable way of getting position of objects that's crossbrowser? Thx

Comment: jQuery's `position()`? It works for DOM elements, the `document` object, and the `window` object, so you're covered.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, assuming you have an element named `elem`, it's actually quite easy to get the X and Y coordinates of the top-left corners of an element, assuming you want these in *document coordinates*. In all browsers this is returned by the `elem.offsetLeft` and `elem.offsetTop` properties.

The only trick you have to be aware of is that if `elem` is absolutely positioned in another element, say a `div` with a left / top margin of 20px, these properties will return 0, as it only takes into account the current element and not the entire chain of elements. Luckily we can use a "chain-traversal" function to capture all of the margins of elements associated with a given element, tally them up to get the correct document coordinates.

As Sime Vidas mentioned, there is also JQuery's `position()` and `offset()` properties, in this case you would want the `offset()` properties.

You can also use the `getBoundingClientRect()` method, however this returns the coordinates of an element relative to its `offsetParent` and thus is not entirely reliable. Look at the following examples:

```
// getPosition function
function getPosition(elem){

    var dims = {offsetLeft:0, offsetTop:0};

    do {
        dims.offsetLeft += elem.offsetLeft;
        dims.offsetTop += elem.offsetTop;
    }

    while (elem = elem.offsetParent);

    return dims;
}

cont1.style.position = "absolute";
cont1.style.marginLeft = "10px";

cont2.style.position = "absolute";
cont2.style.marginLeft = "10px";

box.style.position = "absolute";
box.style.marginLeft = "10px";


console.log(getPosition(box).offsetLeft); // returns "30"
console.log(getPosition(box).offsetTop); // returns "0"

// or in JQuery
console.log($(box).offset().left) // also returns "30"
console.log($(box).offset().top) // also returns "0"
```

Also I suggest you read [this](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/findpos.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the position of an element relative to document use jQuery `offset()` method.

```
var p = $("p:last");
var offset = p.offset();
p.html( "left: " + offset.left + ", top: " + offset.top );
```

`.offset()` reference: http://api.jquery.com/offset/

If you want to find the poistion of an element relative to its parent then use jQuery `position()` method.

```
var p = $("p:first");
var position = p.position();
$("p:last").text( "left: " + position.left + ", top: " + position.top );
```

`.position()` reference: http://api.jquery.com/position/

And these methods almost gives perfect result in most of the browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I like `element.getBoundingClientRect()`.  It [has good cross-browser support](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_cssom.html#t21).

```
var coords = element.getBoundingClientRect();
```

This gives the coordinates relative to the viewport.  To get the coordinates relative to the document, add `document.documentElement.scrollTop` to the `top` and `document.documentElement.scrollLeft` to the `left`.

```
coords.top += document.documentElement.scrollTop;
coords.left += document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
```

But since you are already using jQuery, you may as well just use [`.offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset).